# display button in the correct place

Tags: html, css

I have 7 buttons to display in my html page,

These buttons represents the days number as in this picture :

[image]

I'm using a javascript function that display only buttons of specific days (in my case : days that have null value on the chart) ...

However when the button are hidden I lose the correct position of the rest of buttons (that I should have).. like in this picture :

[image]

I want that the buttons keep there correct positions. What I want have is something like this :

[image]

Here is my Html code :

```
   <div id="graph-wrapper" style="height:200px; width:100%; display:inline-block;">   <table class="graph-actions">
        <tr>
          <td id="graph-edit0" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 1</td>
          <td id="graph-edit1" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 2</td>
          <td id="graph-edit2" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 3</td>
          <td id="graph-edit3" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 4</td>
          <td id="graph-edit4" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 5</td>
          <td id="graph-edit5" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 6</td>
          <td id="graph-edit6" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 7</td>
        </tr>       </table>  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of using hidden which corresponds to the CSS `display:none;` rule, you can use the `visibility:hidden;` CSS for the buttons that you don't want to be displayed.

Comment: `<td id="graph-edit0" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 1</td>` instead of using the "hidden" class, try to add `opacity: 0` in the style

Comment: Please provide a working sample, including your CSS. Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: opacity is not a great solution. will keep your buttons on screen. Just It'll make them transparent. But They'll be there.... watching at you

Comment: That's right @RokoC.Buljan .. it is not a good solution for me , because I can click on button with opacity = 0 !!

Comment: @taboubim exactly. You should go for `visibility`.

Comment: I m trying your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `.hidden` in CSS does

```
display:none;
```

it will collapse the remaining cells to the available space. Instead try like:

```
td.hidden{
    display: table-cell; /* reset the .hidden */
    visibility: hidden;  /* use visibility instead*/
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility
**Here's a demo**:

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
/* the above is from Bootstrap? OK, let's keep it.*/

/* Now let's fix it instead for the TD elements: */
td.hidden{
  display: table-cell;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="graph-wrapper" style="height:200px; width:100%; display:inline-block;">
  <table class="graph-actions">
    <tr>
      <td id="graph-edit0" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 1</td>
      <td id="graph-edit1" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 2</td>
      <td id="graph-edit2" class="btn" style="width: 14%">btn 3</td>
      <td id="graph-edit3" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 4</td>
      <td id="graph-edit4" class="btn" style="width: 14%">btn 5</td>
      <td id="graph-edit5" class="btn" style="width: 14%">btn 6</td>
      <td id="graph-edit6" class="btn hidden" style="width: 14%">btn 7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Roko C. Buljan : your solution is working fine for me .. 
What I've done is having visibility:hidden for all button, after that I use Jquery for editing the css for the given buttons ($("#graph-edit"+value).css("visibility","visible");)

Comment: @taboubim yes, that would be the inverse of what you had, just using `visibility`. Greatly done. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

After correction, and to summarize here is the response :

I edit my code to be as follow :

```
<div id="graph-wrapper" style="height:200px; width:100%; display:inline-block;">
    <table class="graph-actions" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td id="graph-edit0" class="btn " style="width: 14%;visibility: hidden">btn 1</td>
            <td id="graph-edit1" class="btn " style="width: 14%;visibility: hidden">btn 2</td>
            <td id="graph-edit2" class="btn " style="width: 14%;visibility: hidden">btn 3</td>
            <td id="graph-edit3" class="btn " style="width: 14%;visibility: hidden">btn 4</td>
            <td id="graph-edit4" class="btn " style="width: 14%;visibility: hidden">btn 5</td>
            <td id="graph-edit5" class="btn " style="width: 14%;visibility: hidden">btn 6</td>
            <td id="graph-edit6" class="btn " style="width: 14%;visibility: hidden">btn 7</td>
        </tr>
    </table> </div>
```

And I used a JQuery function to edit the css for the given buttons as this :

```
$.each( indexesNullValue(data),function( index, value ){
        $("#graph-edit"+value).css("visibility","visible");
    });
```

Thank you all :)